# validate table data based on criteria defined in a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have defined different validations criteria depending upon the business need in a table and provide relevant error messages to be shown in case validation criteria not meets as show in given screenshot.

[image: Validation Table]

I have written down a plsql package which will dynamically validate a single validation based on passed value and given value in `REF_CHECK_DATA` column, function is working fine however the issue is business need to define N no of validations in future which will be either static expression or based on any plsql function the package should handle it dynamically in one call. below is the existing function which will handle only one validation passed as parameter to package.

```
PROCEDURE pr_run_field_val (p_id             IN  NUMBER    DEFAULT NULL,
                                p_sch_cat_grp_id IN  NUMBER    DEFAULT NULL,
                                p_val_category   IN  NUMBER    DEFAULT NULL,
                                p_field_id       IN  NUMBER    DEFAULT NULL,                                
                                p_field_value    IN  VARCHAR2  DEFAULT NULL,
                                p_value_type     IN  VARCHAR2              ,
                                p_param_val1     IN  VARCHAR2  DEFAULT NULL,
                                p_param_val2     IN  VARCHAR2  DEFAULT NULL,
                                p_param_val3     IN  VARCHAR2  DEFAULT NULL,
                                p_param_val4     IN  VARCHAR2  DEFAULT NULL,
                                p_param_val5     IN  VARCHAR2  DEFAULT NULL,
                                p_param_val6     IN  VARCHAR2  DEFAULT NULL,
                                p_param_val7     IN  VARCHAR2  DEFAULT NULL,
                                p_param_val8     IN  VARCHAR2  DEFAULT NULL,
                                p_param_val9     IN  VARCHAR2  DEFAULT NULL,
                                o_status         OUT VARCHAR2,
                                o_error_codes    OUT VARCHAR2,
                                o_status_text    OUT VARCHAR2)
    IS

        CURSOR c IS 
           SELECT DECODE (V ('G_LANG'), 'ar-om', b.name_ar, b.name_en)          scheme_category,
           DECODE (V ('G_LANG'), 'ar-om', val_cat.name_ar, val_cat.name_en)     validation_category,
           DECODE (a.action_type, 'I', 'Insert', 'Edit')                        action_type,
           DECODE (V ('G_LANG'), 'ar-om', val_op.name_ar, val_op.name_en)       validation_operator,
           val_op.dtl_code operator_sign,
           val_op.attribute_01 operator_code,
           DECODE (V ('G_LANG'), 'ar-om', val_field.name_ar, val_field.name_en) field_name,
           DECODE (V ('G_LANG'), 'ar-om', val_service.name_ar, val_service.name_en) service,
           A.ref_check_data,
           A.data_type,
           a.error_code,
           DECODE (V ('G_LANG'), 'ar-om', description_ar, description_en)    error_message,
           a.id,
           value_type, 
           condition_operator, 
           paranthesis, 
           val_seq       
      FROM  mst_dyn_validation a
           ,scheme_cat_group   b
           ,mst_lookup_header  val_cat
           ,mst_lookup_dtl     val_op
           ,mst_lookup_dtl     val_field
           ,mst_lookup_dtl     val_service
     WHERE 1=1 
           AND a.sch_cat_grp_id = b.sch_cat_grp_id
           AND a.val_cat_id     = val_cat.lkp_hdr_id
           AND a.operator_id    = val_op.lkp_dtl_id(+)           
           AND a.field_id       = val_field.lkp_dtl_id(+)
           AND a.service_id     = val_service.lkp_dtl_id           
           AND a.field_id       = a.field_id
           AND a.id             = NVL(p_id,a.id)
           AND a.sch_cat_grp_id = NVL(p_sch_cat_grp_id, a.sch_cat_grp_id)
           AND a.field_id       = NVL(p_field_id,a.field_id)
           AND a.value_type     = NVL(p_value_type,a.value_type)
           AND a.val_cat_id     = NVL(p_val_category,a.val_cat_id)
           ORDER BY a.val_seq;
        
        
        l_check_val   VARCHAR2 (1000);
        l_min_val     VARCHAR2 (1000);
        l_max_val     VARCHAR2 (1000);
        l_cnt         VARCHAR2 (1000);
        l_date        DATE;
    BEGIN
        
        FOR cur IN c LOOP
            
            IF cur.DATA_TYPE = 'DATE' AND UPPER(cur.REF_CHECK_DATA) LIKE '%SYSDATE%' AND cur.operator_code <> 'Between'THEN

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select '||cur.REF_CHECK_DATA||' from dual' INTO l_date;
                l_check_val := to_char(l_date,'DD-MM-YYYY');

            ELSE        
                 IF cur.value_type = 'PLSQL' THEN
                   
                    IF p_param_val1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                    
                        l_check_val :=  REPLACE (
                                            REPLACE (
                                                REPLACE (
                                                    REPLACE (
                                                        REPLACE (
                                                            REPLACE (
                                                                REPLACE (
                                                                    REPLACE (
                                                                        REPLACE (cur.REF_CHECK_DATA,
                                                                                 ':1',
                                                                                 p_param_val1),
                                                                             ':2',
                                                                            p_param_val2),
                                                                         ':3',
                                                                        p_param_val3),
                                                                     ':4',
                                                                    p_param_val4),
                                                                 ':5',
                                                                p_param_val5),
                                                             ':6',
                                                            p_param_val6),
                                                         ':7',
                                                        p_param_val7),
                                                     ':8',
                                                    p_param_val8),
                                                 ':9',
                                                p_param_val9);
                    END IF;
                    
                   -- dbms_output.put_line (l_check_val);
                    
                    SELECT apex_plugin_util.get_plsql_expression_result  (l_check_val) INTO l_check_val FROM DUAL;
                
                ELSE
                    l_check_val := cur.REF_CHECK_DATA;
                END IF;
                
            END IF; 
            
       
            IF  REPLACE (NVL(p_field_value,l_check_val), ' ') IS NULL AND cur.operator_code = 'NotNull' THEN
                
                o_status := 'N';
                o_status_text := 'Failed';
                append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                
              --  dbms_output.put_line (l_check_val);
                
            END IF;
            
            IF  REPLACE (NVL(p_field_value,l_check_val), ' ') IS NOT NULL AND cur.operator_code = 'IsNull' THEN
                
                o_status := 'N';
                o_status_text := 'Failed';
                append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);                
              --  dbms_output.put_line (l_check_val);
              
            END IF;
            
            IF cur.operator_code = 'Dymanic' THEN
            
               IF cur.data_type IN ('NUMBER') THEN
               
                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select COUNT(1) from dual where '||p_field_value||' IN ('||cur.REF_CHECK_DATA||')' 
                  
                  INTO l_cnt;   
    
                  IF l_cnt = 0 THEN     
                    o_status := 'N';
                    o_status_text := 'Failed';
                    append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' ||cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                  END IF;
                  
               END IF;
               
               IF cur.data_type IN ('CHAR') THEN
                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select COUNT(1) from dual where '''||p_field_value||''' IN ('||cur.REF_CHECK_DATA||')' 
                  INTO l_cnt;   
    
                  IF l_cnt = 0 THEN     
                    o_status := 'N';
                    o_status_text := 'Failed';
                    append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                  END IF;
               END IF;
               
               IF cur.data_type IN ('DATE') THEN 

                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select COUNT(1) from dual where TO_DATE('''||p_field_value||''',''DD-MM-YYYY'') IN ('||cur.REF_CHECK_DATA||')' 
                  INTO l_cnt;
    
                  IF l_cnt = 0 THEN     
                    o_status := 'N';
                    o_status_text := 'Failed';
                    append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                  END IF;
                END IF;
                

            END IF;
            
            IF cur.operator_code = 'Between' THEN
            
                l_min_val := SUBSTR(cur.REF_CHECK_DATA,1,INSTR(cur.REF_CHECK_DATA,'$') - 1);
                l_max_val := SUBSTR(cur.REF_CHECK_DATA,INSTR(cur.REF_CHECK_DATA,'$') + 1);
                
                IF cur.data_type IN ('NUMBER') THEN
                    IF NOT TO_NUMBER (p_field_value) BETWEEN TO_NUMBER (l_min_val) AND TO_NUMBER (l_max_val) THEN
                        o_status := 'N';
                        o_status_text := 'Failed';
                        append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                    END IF;
                END IF;
                
                IF cur.data_type IN ('DATE') THEN

                    IF UPPER(l_min_val) LIKE '%SYSDATE%' THEN
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select '||l_min_val||' from dual' INTO l_date;
                        l_min_val := to_char(l_date,'DD-MM-YYYY');
                    END IF;
                    
                    IF UPPER(l_max_val) LIKE '%SYSDATE%' THEN
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select '||l_max_val||' from dual' INTO l_date;
                        l_max_val := to_char(l_date,'DD-MM-YYYY');
                    END IF;
                    

                    IF NOT TO_DATE (p_field_value, 'DD-MM-YYYY') BETWEEN TO_DATE (l_min_val, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND TO_DATE (l_max_val, 'DD-MM-YYYY') THEN
                        o_status := 'N';
                        o_status_text := 'Failed';
                        append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' ||cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                    END IF;
                END IF;    
            END IF;
            
            IF cur.operator_code = 'Equal' THEN
            
                IF cur.data_type IN ('NUMBER') THEN
                
                    IF TO_NUMBER (p_field_value) <> TO_NUMBER (l_check_val) THEN
                        o_status := 'N';
                        o_status_text := 'Failed';
                        append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                    END IF;
                    
                END IF;
                
                IF cur.data_type IN ('CHAR') THEN
                
                    IF p_field_value <> l_check_val THEN
                        o_status := 'N';
                        o_status_text := 'Failed';
                        append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                    END IF;
                    
                END IF;
                
                IF cur.data_type IN ('DATE') THEN
                    IF TO_DATE (p_field_value, 'DD-MM-YYYY') <> TO_DATE (l_check_val, 'DD-MM-YYYY') THEN
                        o_status := 'N';
                        o_status_text := 'Failed';
                        append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                    END IF;
                END IF;

            END IF;
        
            IF cur.operator_code = 'NotEqual' THEN
            
                IF cur.data_type IN ('NUMBER') THEN
                    IF TO_NUMBER (p_field_value) = TO_NUMBER (l_check_val) THEN
                        o_status := 'N';
                        o_status_text := 'Failed';
                        append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                    END IF;
                END IF;
                
                IF cur.data_type IN ('CHAR') THEN
                    IF p_field_value = l_check_val THEN
                        o_status := 'N';
                        o_status_text := 'Failed';
                        append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                    END IF; 
                END IF;
                
                IF cur.data_type IN ('DATE') THEN
                    IF TO_DATE (p_field_value, 'DD-MM-YYYY') = TO_DATE (l_check_val, 'DD-MM-YYYY') THEN
                        o_status := 'N';
                        o_status_text := 'Failed';
                        append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                    END IF;
                END IF;

            END IF;
            
            IF cur.operator_code = 'GreaterThan' THEN
                IF cur.data_type IN ('NUMBER') THEN
                    IF NOT TO_NUMBER (p_field_value) > TO_NUMBER (l_check_val) THEN
                        o_status := 'N';
                        o_status_text := 'Failed';
                        append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                    END IF;
                END IF;
               

                IF cur.data_type IN ('DATE') THEN
                
                    IF NOT TO_DATE (p_field_value, 'DD-MM-YYYY') > TO_DATE (l_check_val, 'DD-MM-YYYY') THEN
                        o_status := 'N';
                        o_status_text := 'Failed';
                        append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                    
                    END IF;
                END IF;

            END IF;
            
            IF cur.operator_code = 'GreaterThanEqual' THEN
                IF cur.data_type IN ('NUMBER') THEN
                    IF NOT TO_NUMBER (p_field_value) >= TO_NUMBER (l_check_val) THEN
                        o_status := 'N';
                        o_status_text := 'Failed';
                        append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' ||cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                    END IF;
                END IF;
               

                IF cur.data_type IN ('DATE') THEN
                
                    IF NOT TO_DATE (p_field_value, 'DD-MM-YYYY') >= TO_DATE (l_check_val, 'DD-MM-YYYY') THEN
                        o_status := 'N';
                        o_status_text := 'Failed';
                        append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                    
                    END IF;
                END IF;

            END IF;
            
            IF cur.operator_code = 'LessThan' THEN
                IF cur.data_type IN ('NUMBER') THEN
                    IF NOT TO_NUMBER (p_field_value) < TO_NUMBER (l_check_val) THEN
                        o_status := 'N';
                        o_status_text := 'Failed';
                        append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                    END IF;
                END IF;
               

                IF cur.data_type IN ('DATE') THEN
                
                    IF NOT TO_DATE (p_field_value, 'DD-MM-YYYY') < TO_DATE (l_check_val, 'DD-MM-YYYY') THEN
                        o_status := 'N';
                        o_status_text := 'Failed';
                        append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                    
                    END IF;
                END IF;

            END IF;
            
            IF cur.operator_code = 'LessThanEqual' THEN
                
                IF cur.data_type IN ('NUMBER') THEN
                    IF NOT TO_NUMBER (p_field_value) <= TO_NUMBER (l_check_val) THEN
                        o_status := 'N';
                        o_status_text := 'Failed';
                        append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                    END IF;
                END IF;

                IF cur.data_type IN ('DATE') THEN
                
                    IF NOT TO_DATE (p_field_value, 'DD-MM-YYYY') <= TO_DATE (l_check_val, 'DD-MM-YYYY') THEN
                        o_status := 'N';
                        o_status_text := 'Failed';
                        append_err_code (cur.ERROR_CODE|| ' - ' || cur.error_message, o_error_codes);
                    
                    END IF;
                END IF;

            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        
        IF NVL (o_status, 'Y') = 'Y' THEN
            o_status := 'Y';
            o_status_text := 'Success';
        END IF;
 
    END;  

END pkg_dyn_validation_1;
```

Looking for idea where i can call the package once for example group A validations, and it will execute all validations and provide status based on each validation.

Comment: Is the issue simply that you need to return multiple statuses? You can return a collection... create an object type for your record with (id,status,error_code,status_txt) columns and a table type of that object type, then make that table type the OUT parameter type. Populate the collection inside your loop.

Comment: For a group there will be N no of validation with different static or PLSQL criteria , can i have a possible approach where i can validate all validations in one call by passing different parameters.

Comment: If you have a group id in your validations table, you can simply pass in the group id to pick up the correct validations. Or if it's a many-to-many, you create a group table and a group_validations bridge table, and populate the associations in the bridge table. Either way, you only need a group id as a parameter input.

Comment: exactly group id will pick multiple validations from table which have different operator and different values to compare from input parameter. so how i can execute different criterias inside package for particular group id , because each validation inside a group need different parameters to be passed to evaluate expression either static or plsql

Comment: Well now if that's the case, then you shouldn't define groups at all. Just provide a collection input and output. The input collection would be a table of validation records, holding the validation id and comparison parameter. The output collection would be a table of results, holding the validation id and whatever status cols you want. You join the input collection using the TABLE() operator to your validation table to get the correct validation rows to work...